# mysql_fetch_assoc does not work for stored procedure output, but works with a normal sql_query

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i have been trying to use mysql_fetch_assoc to the results that obtain through my stored proceedure.. but i keep on getting the error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
```

I checked all similar questions in this site related to this. but none could sought out this issue

```
$excute = mysql_query("CALL Dummy_2('table_1')");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
var_dump($result);
```

**returns an error**

```
$excute = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
var_dump($result);
```

**works fine**

error returns only with the stored procedure, normal query works fine

in case the stored procedure

```
BEGIN   

SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
FROM    ",table_1," a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR)
GROUP BY ID;");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
```

Comment: this is not a duplicate.. this is a problem with a stored procedure and a normal query

Comment: try `$excute = mysql_query("SELECT Dummy_2('table_1')");`

Comment: actually this is inside a loop,as an example table_x and x increases one by one... when i tried your answer table_1 worked, but from table_2 to the the end shows the above warning/error

Comment: what does it display if you execute SELECT Dummy_2('table_2') directly in mysql query/workbench

Comment: it correctly returns the data!!! now the error occurs when it is inside the loop, that i told you

Comment: is it a problem like data cant be fetched twice or something

Comment: hmm thats a weird problem, and via php does `SELECT Dummy_2('table_2')` works if outside the loop?

Comment: yeah it works.. if we call one table(hard coded) it works but not inside the loop

Comment: I think you should add your loop to your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716838/mysql-fetch-array-does-not-work-inside-the-while-loop