# mysql_fetch_array does not work inside the while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have 10 tables known as(table_1,table_2,table_3 etc), currently i want get the result set of each of those tables inside a loop but currently it is returning an error.

it works fine like this

```
$excute = ("CALL Dummy_2('table_1')");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($excute));
var_dump($result);
```

Result

```
array (size=8)
  'ID' => string '1' (length=3)
  'name' => string 'Test_E' (length=11)
  'accountname' => string 'sri01' (length=3)
  'accountID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'status' => string '2' (length=1)
  'total_mps' => string '202' (length=3)
  'min(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-05-16 05:38:01' (length=19)
  'max(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-12-31 03:41:31' (length=19)
```

but when i put it inside a loop to fulfill my requirement it returns 9 errors(equal to the remaining number of tables) along with the first result set

```
$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'milepostdb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){
$table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

$excute = ("CALL Dummy_2('{$table}')");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($excute));
var_dump($result);
}
```

The error

```
 array (size=8)
      'ID' => string '1' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Test_E' (length=11)
      'accountname' => string 'sri01' (length=3)
      'accountID' => string '1' (length=1)
      'status' => string '2' (length=1)
      'total_mps' => string '202' (length=3)
      'min(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-05-16 05:38:01' (length=19)
      'max(a.timestamp)' => string '2014-12-31 03:41:31' (length=19)

( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean .......

null

( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean .......

null

( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean .......

null

etc
```

Comment: Check for $table_count, it is coming out to be null.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're passing mysql_fetch_assoc a bad parameter, so work backwards from there and see why it's bad.

Comment: thanks for your responses guys... ill look into the lapse

Comment: but when i run the table_count(identical query) in a standalone query browser it returns the tables correctly

Answer (score 0):

The function mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($excute)) returns NULL when the query is not executed successfully.

Try replacing $execute as follows.

$excute = "CALL Dummy_2('".$table."')";

In your case the table name is searched as {$table} and the variable is not replaced in the query. This results is a wrong search and no tables will be found.